# tcshrc setting path getting error

Tags: batch-file, csh

im trying to set the environment path to run pintos command like this in my home floder under ubuntu

```
set path = ($path /home/pintos/src/utils)
```

and I type terminal command try to compile this

```
:~$ source .tcshrc
```

but it seems get error like this

```
 bash: .tcshrc: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
 bash: .tcshrc: line 1: `set path = ($path /home/pintos/src/utils)'
```

I dont know where is the syntax error is ...

Comment: try to add quotes around `'/home/pintos/src/utils'`

Comment: thanks, ive tried but still cannot work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `source` your script, which is perfectly valid for `[t]csh`, into your running shell, which happens to be `bash` (and *not* `tcsh`).

If you're going to use `tcsh`, just run it (by typing `tcsh`) and ensure that your `~/.tcshrc` has the desired effect. (Then, maybe, use `chsh` to change your login shell).

If you're going to use `bash`, set path using `PATH=$PATH:/home/pintos/src/utils`, in `~/.bashrc` and/or in `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: thank you ! could you give me some instructions to set this right ?

Comment: In the end, which shell do you want? (I already gave some ideas for both variants, you can start with them and post more questions if you're stuck)

Comment: ...and if you want `tcsh`, do you *have* `tcsh` installing? Try to run it, maybe you'll have to install it first.

Comment: @alfasin the errors described above are caused by an attempt to use *tcsh* syntax for *bash* shell (those shells aren't compatible, they have different historical roots and remain different)